# Get nested attribute from a python object

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr

I have an object with nested attributes like so:

```
obj:
    attr_1:
        attr_2
```

When both `attr_1` and `attr_2` exists, I can get it like so:

```
obj.attr_1.attr_2
```

But what if I'm not sure if either attribute exists? In this case, construction of `getattr(obj, 'attr_1.attr_2', None)` does not work.

What are the best practices to replace this construction?

Divide that into two `getattr` statements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getattr and setattr on nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174295/getattr-and-setattr-on-nested-objects)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`operator.attrgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) in order to get multiple attributes at once:

```
from operator import attrgetter

my_attrs = attrgetter(attr1, attr2)(obj)
```

Comment: I think OP wants `my_attrs = ('attr1.attr2')(obj)`

Comment: The title says something different though.

Comment: @elena yes, the title makes this ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry. I want to get `obj.attr1.attr2` using getattr or another method.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11975810/9813264), the most straightforward solution would be to use [operator.attrgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) (more info in [this python docs page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter)).

If for some reason, this solution doesn't make you happy, you could use this code snippet:

```
def multi_getattr(obj, attr, default = None):
"""
Get a named attribute from an object; multi_getattr(x, 'a.b.c.d') is
equivalent to x.a.b.c.d. When a default argument is given, it is
returned when any attribute in the chain doesn't exist; without
it, an exception is raised when a missing attribute is encountered.

"""
attributes = attr.split(".")
for i in attributes:
    try:
        obj = getattr(obj, i)
    except AttributeError:
        if default:
            return default
        else:
            raise
return obj

# Example usage
obj  = [1,2,3]
attr = "append.__doc__.capitalize.__doc__"

multi_getattr(obj, attr) #Will return the docstring for the
                         #capitalize method of the builtin string
                         #object
```

from [this page](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577346-getattr-with-arbitrary-depth/), which does work. I tested and used it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using python's built-in [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
from operator import attrgetter
attrgetter('attr0.attr1.attr2.attr3')(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the attribute names you want to get in a list, you can do the following:

```
my_attrs = [getattr(obj, attr) for attr in attr_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple, but not very eloquent way, to get multiple attr would be to use tuples with or without brackets something like

```
aval, bval =  getattr(myObj,"a"), getattr(myObj,"b")
```

but I think you might be wanting instead to get atrribute of a contained object with the way you are using dot notation.  In which case it would be something like

```
getattr(myObj.contained, "c")
```

where contained is an object cotained within myObj object and c is an attribute of contained.  Let me know if this is not what you want.